# How to display image from sql server in ms access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, image, ms-access

I have an MS sql server database. There is a table with one of the column of the "image" type. Now, the customer wants to read the data from an MS access. He wants to display the images in a form.
I have never used access and have no idea of how to do simple things there. Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Thanks,
Ramjee

Comment: The first thing to check is to see if Access will treat the image column the same way it treats its own OLE fields. That is, it's remotely possible to bind an image control on an Access form directly to the field. It probably won't work, but try before you start coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put regular Image control on form and state MyPic.PictureData=PicField in Current event.

Or you can use AccessImagine, which is great for pictures in MS Access and requires no scripting. You can download it here - http://access.bukrek.net/download

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write out the stored images to files in order to display them, it may be possible to use ASP to display the image and a web browser control on the Access form to display the page. I have not tried this.

How To Display Images Stored in a BLOB Field: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173308

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using streams. Stream the image from the field to an unbound image control. We use the same process for opening documents and other binary data stored in an SQL Server database.

---

On the other hand, Access had an Image control that can be linked to a field in a table. That should be a lot easier to user!