# View Image file stored in SQL Server in MS Access form

Tags: sql, vba, image, ms-access

I am trying to make an MS Access form to view 64Bit *.jpg images stored in a SQL Server table

I am new to this, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

The images are stored in SQL as:
Field Name: [ImageBody]
Field Data Type: Image
Sample data below:

0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB004300100B0C0E0C0A100E0D0E1211101318281A181616183123251D283A333D3C3933383740485C4E404457453738506D51575F626768673E4D71797064785C656763FFDB0043011112121815182F1A1A2F634238426363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363FFC0001108014C00BB03012200021101031101FFC4001F0000010501010101010100000000000000000102030405060708090A0BFFC400B5100002010303020403050504040000017D01020300041105122131410613516107227114328191A1082342B1C11552D1F02433627282090A161718191A25262728292A3435363738393A434445464748494A535455565758595A636465666768696A737475767778797A838485868788898A92939495969798999AA2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAB2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BAC2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CAD2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DAE1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAF1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFFC4001F0100030101010101010101010000000000000102030405060708090A0BFFC400B51100020102040403040705040400010277000102031104052131061241510761711322328108144291A1B1C109233352F0156272D10A162434E125F11718191A262728292A35363738393A434445464748494A535455565758595A636465666768696A737475767778797A82838485868788898A92939495969798999AA2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAB2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BAC2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CAD2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DAE2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAF2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFFDA000C03010002110311003F00F3FA28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28A2800A28345001451450014514500145145001450013D053C44E7A29A00651528B790F603F1A70B56EEC28020A2AC8B51DDE9C2DA3EE4FE7401528AB8B0447A0CFE34E10A0FE11401469704F406AF8451FC23F2A70E28028089CF443F95385BCA7F86AF668CD0228FD9E4F4FD693C87F4ABC45348A00A7E4BFA52F90FED56714628194D8629B573CA43D4669EA8A3A28A00A2158F4069E2190FF000D5DC5281401505B39EA40A78B51DD8D5902942D005610443BE7F1A7AA4638099FC2A60A076A7014088867B252E1CFA0A97146280232BEF8A367B9A976D1B68021F2D7D294201D854BB68DB401181ED4629FB68C500331498A7E298FB811B7A5002518A6E5CE302970F8ED400518A690FD09C500B039661EF400A45253B72F3C8A5DB9A0000A5028460D9C76A781400D02976D3C0A502801A16940A78141C0EA40A006E28C52EF51C67AFA5390861919FC6801A01A705A762940A0066DA5DB4FC518A008F1462A4C52628023C51B6A4DB46DA6045B690AE411EB52EDA08A00ADE49E80E3E8290438EA735676D262802B790B9EF41841C75AB1B6936D202BF94BE94E0302A42B49B680228C04CF3927D2A4049E887F1E2A40B4E02802301C8E801A5D8C71F391F415285A705A0088460F5C9FC69E2318E838A785A701400C0A00E05382D3C0A31400CC7B518A7E28CAE71919A006629714E52AC4853C8EB4E0B4C08C0A5DB5205A36D00478A36D49B68DB40116DA4C54DB690AD0042568DB52EDA36D0042569BB6A6DB49B680222B4DDB5315A6EDA006814E038A458DF20EFE3D31D69C205CF393CE793EF4007CA0649A4F3A3CE33FA54891281B40E2A41181D8714010EF247CA8C4E71CD00CA4FF00ABC7BE6AC85A080A0962001DCD0041B25627E6503DA9DE4B107739E7D38A92496285599DC00A707BE2A27BEB740DF316DAA18803B1C7F88A005FB3A9FBD96FA9A72C08BD17F3E6A26D4A20CEA11BE470AC4F619EBF4FF1A0DEB79D711F9603423775CE5475FD2802C84C7414BB6A85C5E4C9E49DCAAAC4A3903A11C67FAD432DCCDE4C32B48C00631CA071CFF8E2901ADB69ADB46016009381CF5AC466919D56572776626CB7191D0FF2FC8D4B3EE96DD2619120E4FA865EBF98C1FC28034CCB12A96322E0120F3DC531AEA00A1B7E415DC300F22AA022463B465675F3107FB63EF0FC79A8221FBA923FBC613E6267F890F51F950068B5DC4B11906E650A1B8F4CE2A16D462001DAD8C8C9F407BD57B52155E26F9963F987FB519EBFD0D40D118DDE17FE0F949FF64F43F81C1FC6802F25E9937A88B0EB91B73DC76FE7F9535AEDD94F96ABF326F4CF7C751F5AAB1473875611BEE1F237CA7823A1FF003E86ACF912FCDE5A118C4B1E7B1EEB400D178CD1AC9C0507E600763DFF00034C134C4491B4989139CE3A8F5FF3DAA58ECE549DB6A7EE9B9C13D33D47F9F414BF61954C6C1977467009EEBE86802A99A4122B966DAFC1527EEB77152EDDDCF94CFF00ED6EC66A66B0077AEFF95874C743D8D2AD9800032C99F638A007BDCC31960CDCA0C9007F9F5A25BA58A3918296D983E99CD675D0FF004AB91FEC8FE956A44692DA40A09668633803AF26801EB7ACE25DA80158C38CF39F5A8EE6EA74B99E247C00B95E07B1FE59A2D2DA53C346CBBA0284918C1C9A9A4B09A69D25F957316D6C9E72411400CB891DEDA52198168924001E9EB50419912553CF9B00603DD781FCAB4A3B16F2151DC6E1118C903D7A7E54EB7D36381E360CE5932064FAD005261E759B7FD3480367DD0F3FCEA9A0DED09EBE6218CFD7A0FF00D96B7C5BDB5B469BB6A2A642966F5EBD68DB690AA1544F98E5022673EE31401831A34AEA1549F362DA703A11C0FD547E7579609DAEED6E044C7726D94118F624D68FDA6325444AD29605805C741F5C50D72A6DD64894BB39C2A1E0E7BE7E98340141F4F964B6784E0720A127B8E3FF0041029CBA648D14A92BAE240A7239C30EA7F1ABC1E496059D1D110A6E20AE48F5E73511697EC2B70F3321F2C1C2A8E49E9D47D29815C6908CA55E56390B9C0C723807F2AB0B61128604B306218827BF73F8F7A1D5CCF08B8668C3C781B18801FBFF009F6A864449EC37491C666671196C753BB1914013A59DB4612355FB87728DC720D08969E6ED4F2BCCE460633EF49791283F20556043E04449620FA8A4B8569238DC24824003AC6172BBBDCFFF005C5003A3306E611A729919119038ED9C5235C22E772B8C296E57A81D689A1700B431C8B2BFCD9593E50DEE09FE952989CDCA4871B42107EA48FF000A0080DCA04625183000ED38C9C9C0EF8A512B3A8312A3FAFCFC0FCAA31A791FBBF9761CEE6C9CB039EA3A7E3520B593716F3403B0A02AB8FA13CD0042D759116C1B4499EAA4F4ED8153AB2C8BB94E474FA522DAE225466C85C6DDA3183EB4F8E11186C12C58E493D4D0034AD262A42B9A6EDA0060B78CB97F2D4B1EA71CD4CAB814A169E0500412485248E345059F38C9C0005442E9E496384011B976563D7A0CF1F9D5996DFCD6470C55D0FCA47BF5140B28B690DB998B6FDD9C1CFE140153CE91E74825720090AB329DB9E32BF4FF00EB534B1F382CCDBEDE294AB16E47238CFD0D692DAC4B198FCB0549C90DF364FA9CD4B1C4B1A85450AA3A003028032A256132CB1A992DE29182E067E52074F500D490DBCAB2F9E887689188463825481F9723A569EDA705A00CE86CA5590CCA5564F319829E46D38E0FE59A962B045CB484B39767CA92B8CF51C1F615776D382D00528EC618EDE485010AF9C9E3383EF52496D1CAA8AEBC21CAE09183F8559DB46DA00805BC7E594D80A9EA0F39A7040AA02A8007402A6C52638A008B146DA93146DA0088AD34AD4DB6936D004045262A52B4DC500478A6E2A5C5348A00888A6E054B8A4C5002AAD3C0A5514E5140005A7014E0BC53C2D00342D2EDA785A701401185A50B521C00492060679A624D0B6C292A37999D841CEEC75C5000053B6D516D66C961695646915485215483939C75C7A1A6CDAD431C723244EEC81588381C30C83FA8FCE803436D18F5ACF4D54CA25090E196DFCE439C86E391F9F151C3A9CF716092A845919DA2385E376D2571F8E07E3401ABB68DB58B797F742FA158A5221BA88141B47CACC3039FAE0D569EF67FB1D95E2CB21D8DE5CAA1C80C41C8C8F719A00E84AD31E48E2199244418CE5881EDFD4572F33342C92EE321B6976E5BF890F2BF9FCDF98AB9146AD672405B2B049B431FF9E6FD0FE786FC280367CF877A20914B48094C73B80F4A806A16CF2F951B97729BC281D4633C67BE2B1AD9DD6C33B489AC25DD8E9F293C8FCE96FF0016B751DCC3CAA3075C70191B247EBB87E22802F8D62074531C7212DB800703240CE3AF7E29906ABF6831AAC414C818292DC6E1D8FE18E7DEB3AE62F26F248E13849809A023D79231FA803DC544B9F34AC585F340961C7671D87FE3C3DCE28034A3D46696E1E0D88ACE9BA1383C9F43FA8FC2A07D4265FB3DC163E437C92A607CAC3AFBFBD477A37AC77707CA5BF7ABEC47DE1F81C1FF00BEAA421273C7105F2E47FB128FFEBFE7400921713B4134AC6394796493D0FF000B0FAFF3CD545D46EAD07D9CAA931FCBF3024D58814DCDB341229F360F9180193B73C1F720FE9F5AB11B6507DAB4F9649870CE23CE71C673401A8658A3708F222B3630A48C9FC29B1DE5BBC6248D8BA99047900F53F5FAD63DEB7FC4C6C1FF00D88CFEA6A5B3611585C8FF009E572ADFF8F0FF000A00BF36AB1C57325B8898BC6ACC72400703352DB5F79C6D4850A27573D738231C7F3AC8BB5DDE20993FBE8547E31E2ADE9857EC5A6BE7959993F30DFF00D6A00AA358BC7B6925DE0159106028C6086C8FD05686A465306A31E5BE511BA73D01E0FF00E826B1D936CBA942BD00240FA38FE99ADB447B808370FF0049B1DBFF00021FFED50067694E45E58B67E578DA26FA824E3FF41AB1A76F8AD551986EB5BBDA7FDD3F29FD58D67D80630C2C88EED05C862AA324861FFD87EB5AE6CA4FB5EA912C0DB2640C8C7805B19EBF53FA500654D118EEB51B5E0020BA0FA1DC3FF1D269B18F39221D7CE81A23EA594E547E882B62E74B9E7D5A3BA54558DD0094337A8208FCAA3B4D0A78D104B2C4AD1CC2442A0B63D7D3AE17F2A00A1A5CBB24B197070AED0360F63C8FD58FE5525846F0CDA858AEEDEBF3C5EB95391C7BF15A50F87A245951A6628EE1D768C15C671CF3EA6AE7F66C1FDA1F6DF9BCDC7AF1D31FCA803075041269A248BFE5DE5CAE0F447F987F303F0A48D7ED30DEC007FAD41731003383FC407E3C7E15D12D8DB2C650440A950A41E4100923AFD4D3D2DA08C831C31A151805540C0F4FD680391894DC4480024CB1988E3AEE5C15FD368FCEADE9F04FE642658250B2235BCB94238EC7F503F0AE95D9224DF232A28EEC702A29AEADE154679061FEEED05B77D314018B6FA7DD47A8F99245BA29A3293E08FA13D7B919FC6A41A54EF66904AC8593747BB27943C8FC881C7B5689BE84C65E35964F9B6ED58CE738CF43D28FB5799116821791C36D287E52A719E734019C746792D2DE37B8DB2C0C4AC8AB9E3D3AD3CE896FC10F229572EBB081B49F4E3A7156C5C4F2878A38D239D08DC2439183DC11D7F4A8D5AEA4967B7F3625640843AA7AE73C127D28005B0B7542823F97797C64E32463F2C76A725B431A854891541C801475F5FAD4114DE7DC4B69F6ADE000448A406073CAF1FCC50B18FB6CB6A4BC90188330762769CF4CF5E450058664552ECC028EA73C0AAFF6FB6FF9E87FEF934D48634D48C7022AA08BF78AA30339E38F5EB561E78A362ACE011DA80316FAD6794D8B450C8F885012AA702ADC7A6DCB26A3195082670D192DC1F989EDF856DAAD3C0A00CB9B4969B544BB12850BB4E31927152D9E9296F6C90BC8CFB251282063915A4071540DEDC3A4B3C11C46085883B89DCD8EA47A5004834BB4F39E6F272F267712C79CF5E2AD476F1204091A8D830B81D07B55349E4BDBA78E099A28D2356CAA8CB16E475CF155D2E24BB96D6DAE1B1F3C8928538DE5471D3EB401AE76A29248007249A6A4D0C91B4892A320EAC18102B22EF3019AD725ADE378A4DAC73842791F4CE2A6D4A0DB75B215C1B981D0AAF1920641FE9401761BCB79DB6C6E776DDC37295C8F519EB51C7A846ED19314891CA76C72301863DBBE79AAF34893DB69D346416322AF1D704618543236CD21AC5F8BA8D82C6B8E58E7823F0A00B42FE4D8F70615FB2A39566DFF0030C1C138C74A355BA9A1402D705D54CAF9E7E41FE349224B6F1DE406092549CB346506796EA0FA734E4D319A25325C4C8CD12C6E148C703A6719F5A007CB02CE3CF373308F6EE0A8FB4631EDCFEB505ADAC73E9B04B78CEFB63DC4B39C73CE7AFEB53DB58C91696D6CF26642A5776E2C0761D7DB1C549259092C05AF98C8A14292BD4814019C0B7F6759CF28678E39B71DFC9D872013F8115660516FA94B020C472A79AA074520E0FE7C1AB31DA9427CC9E4994AED28E176E3E800A586CA081CBC684311B72589C0F419E828029D97FABBD767D83CF7F9BFBB8E33FA5456922A5F98E1985D2CC0B48E304A1006324718ED8AD558D5010AA141249C0C734628032625097A8D691DC00E7F7C6556C10071CB739FA5588E175BFB8948F91D5029F5C673FCEAE91498A00CE9AD679E6432C9108E370EBB54EE38FC78A0D89134D22DCCAA652090BB7F2CE3357CAD37140149AC2DDE4323C7BD9B1BB713838F51D2A511A280A140006001DAA6229B8A044C169C052814E02818805662896D61BAB536F23976631155CA90DEA7B7E35AC0735228A00CA86CAE2D1A19210923084452296DB9C7420E29E9A5B34597976DC79A660EA32149EDEE2B4B1CD2814014E2B004CCF72E267986D6F97680BE8053E0B08A09038323B01852EE5B68F4156C0A5C500575B4812632AC31890F560A33F9D4BB79A7EDA5C6280198A4C715262931400CC5262A4C52628023C5262A52B4DC50046569B8A948A6914011E28C53F1498A008C8A6E2A4229A450223229B8A908A6D004E05380A1453C0A06005380A00A70A004029714E02940A006814B8A7628C1A006E28C53FB50003400C14119A7E2931400DC518A7114CDE818A975C819233C81EB400B8A61151497D6E90CB2799B962019B68CF07A1F7AA916B56D3496CA8AF89C9556206011D8F3F4FCC5005F22908AC69F5C9966BB823B74596052CBB9B21803CFA76C9AACDABDD497D0C7E6AA437318D985076B118FD1B8A00E82A392448F1E63AA6E381B8E327D2B1639E5BCD323696460CAED6F3F6C6EE037E076FEB546C95AEB4CBBD3DF227B73E6C60F504751FE7D68037AEF51B5B407CE90820EDC05279C671F91AAF77AB476D730C3B0B09802B2670B83D39AA17606A16514E00DD729B1BA0C4AB9C7E7F30FC455403EDFA091D66B239F7287FCFE940166E35CB94449562455590A4A8796520F4CFB8F6EC6AACFA8EA71CCCB1CAD227556118E41E476F4A629172159BEEDDAF96E7D251D0FE3C7E66A18356BCB4885BAB0511E460AF239A00EED453C0A45148F2C5181E648899381B9B193400F029C0530CF12B48A5BE68D7730EE07F9159C7C416A6D679A18E47109504118CE6803580A7015523BDDF35AA85016E232E0E790460E3F5AC34D62FA59AFA169150C51395DAA382A47F4CD0074F8A63CB1460EF911703272DD07AD655A5D492D9E9770EEC4B48637E7AE430E7F102B24C453C47756F9C09BCC5FFBE9491FD2803A596FEDA28A291A505256DA8CBC827F0A6CF7AB125D158D99ED903919C6E04678FCAB9E1FBFF0882339B797FAFF00F655B2A44F7B1927F777969D3D48FF00EB31A00A13F8867360B730408BFBC31B0725B1C647A7BD367D52F1DEE1525F2D5AD84D1600C8E84FFECD5936C85AC2FEDD81F323DB201E9B4E0FE86AC5A38234D99B91B9ADA4CFA1E9FA37E94012DADFCEC9A7DCC933B049CC526E63839E413F813F954917FA0F8B5D0F0939239EFBB9FE759D6F137D9B51B36FBF1E241EC50E0FE84D5DD7199E2D3B524FBEC8371F461C8FD734017AD630266B4909DAE8F6CDC7F7795FFC758FE55850874B6B88BA4D69289578E983B5BFF65FCAB7EF1D567FB4C792AE8972A47FB3C37FE3AC2B3B50896D7C4B83C437630D8F47183FAF34009ABB243A9DA6A2AB986E10330F518C11FF007C9154AEE064B5922C92F653100FAA3743F98FFC7AAEB46D71E1C96171FBEB194E47538CFF00F5CFE5504389CDB3B11B6E6236D21C7461F74FFE807F0A00B564C935E3C6D810EA50EEE074719CFEBB8FE5555E66B2D5ADEF1BE5127CB30FF687CAFF00E3F8D2D95A5EB5A00904826B6984916E04020F0467A7500FE75A9A968F25EF9A10AA072B22EEECD8C30FCB1F88A00AD1C1E55E5EE9A0EC128F3EDCF4C375E3F11FA550B7956CF58494AED82E87CCA7A0C9C30FC187E55D02E960FD8DE5998CD6C301D46370F4352B69B69236E7815CEE2F86E464F5E3F0A00E59ACDA1BDB9D348387F9A23EE395FD323F1AB69A3A5EA0B89C4F14AE3E7509DFA13F8F5FC6BA5DA28C5017332E9E47D3B554323131C995E7A0C038AC246FF892ABF52975FCD7FF00AD5BD2AE5B598FD5037FE39FFD6AE7EDC6FD16E87FCF3951BF98A00EAC73AD48BFC32DA83F931FF1AE5EC326D7508BFE9906C7FBAC2BA689F3A869F27FCF5B661FC8D73F68BB355BF831F7A39500FCCFF4A00DCB460D6DA34D9E84C7FF008E91FD2B2C47B3C4F3427A4A5D4FFC094FF8D5CD3DF76816AFFF003C6E54FD3E7FF0355B56FDC78A21933C1646FE9FD28026D324FF008A74B1E4DB5C2B7E0181FEA6A2D680B6F12C13E7018A393F8E3FA54FA64798F59B3F42DB7F51FD0526BB6B3DF43613DBC2F23347F36D1D3A1E7F5A0034F8B36FACD881F7492A3F3C7F21562C25DDA6E99707AC52F947E872BFE153D8D8DCC7AC4D72E81629A200F23EF6067F91A7D9690F069D2DA4928C349BD5947DDC1047F2A00C568843E27B8B73C25C6E43FF000219FE7546DC17D2EEE2390F0BACAA3D39DA7F98AEBE7D26DAE2FD2F240E65403001C0E3A1A963D3ED2269192DD03499DC48CE73D7AD0072EA3778823902131DDA02401D9D707F5CD5A8F4EBAB9F0EBDA3C2CB34336630DC6E19F7FA9AE942850028000E8053A80322D74D9BEC3691DC95F321DCADDF284118FD47E54B73A243790DB25C4B2178176EF4C02DD3AE73E95AB5566D42CE0CF99731291D46E19FCA80123B0B78DE6758F99FFD664E437E1D29D15BC502ED86248D739C228151DC6A31432AC4A92CCECBBB112E703D4D32E2FD469E2E6D8090B90AA1B819271CD005AC534D52325C197EC974E23694663961E338EA39CE0D4135925B5E593092592432105E490B1C6D3F85005C3756FE7793E7C7E674DBB866A19EF192668A1B692665C1623000FCFAD41A95B4305935BDBDA33BC992A5549DA7D49AB51CAD71679B6917CC1F296753C11D723D680212F35EC4B25A5C0813A3663CB03E9C9E2B075192EEDEFA4896F672171C96C76CF6ADBB43259DC2D9CA55FCC0D2091463273CE4550D4A12D7D29DA4F4E7F01401A4101D4AF931FEB2053FFA10AE7F4EB4B8934FBE8D60932EA857E53CE1ABB20A01DD819E99A781401996F6B3F97A6394C3400AC809E836E2A18F449175A7BDF31046CC4ED19CF231FD6B6C0A7014019B67A3A5BE9F259BCAD22BB6EC81823A74FCAACCFA75A5C4EB3CF08791460124FF002A99E7861204B2A213D373019A2E2E22B680CB237C83D39CFD2801C90C68CCE91AAB37DE20609A7E2AADAEA115CC8D1EC922900DDB255DA48F5AABFDA178E8F730C11B5AA123049DEC07523B5006A51DAB36E256BEBB82086778A278CCA5A33863E83355AE669E1B4BEB49256768D43239EA509EFF004A00D88E68A52447223E3AED60715525D56DE29DE32B2909C3C8A99553EE6A0BB821B186DEEED6358FCB650DB463729E0E7D69FA6AAB25EDBB804F9CD91EA0F340125DDDCC278ADECD63791D7792E4ED0BF85496774D389125411CD11C3A8391EC47B565D9B18A6B4773F719ED98FE395AB5721D3557F2305E5B66C0F7078FE740115ACF29D58BC8E4C172196319E06D3FD79A9B50B5B7B6D32E5A18238C98C8CAA806A8DE43A84167048C2DE24B62082B9661D8FB77AD1BF8A67D28C4099A460A0955C6EE464E3B500588956381338184009FA0ACB82DDAE748B82A306691A58C7A7391FCAB42FE0967B192181955D86016E063BFE951DBDADD232196ED7CB50008A38C01F99C9A00A77B70B369B05D29C491C8A71DC1CE08FE753DF64DE588C1FF00584FFE3A6AC369F6AD70276814C80E73EFEB8AB0450055B97B84DBF678924CF5DCFB71FA556B6B191629FCF9489277DEC62380BEC3F2AD1229314014ADEC62B790C9B9E4948C6F91B71C7A7B558C0F6A79A4A044A05380A414E1400A29C0520A51C9A06655AC115E5EDEB5C46B2157D8370CE062A9866448E07394B7BC0A33FDDEA2AEB31D3B529A5747682E003B914B6D61EB8A48AC5AF20BB770D119DF72647231D0D004BAA009736538EA24D87DC35268AA3EC12DBB758A47439FAD2ADBDEDCC90FDAC44A90B6EF90E779FE952CDA72C933CB1CF2C0D20C3EC230DF9D006659B1B64B3B97E2252F0B13D8678AB53A4777AB3468C195AD995C8E7193C569456B0C76C2DC2031018C3739A582DA1B75220892307AED5C668031E592E24D3FFB3DADA533F09BB6FC98FEF66AE4B697114FE7D9347BDD42C8B267071D0F15A145006741A70164F0DC9123C8C5DCAF1863E9525AE9F1DB4CD31925965236EE91B240F4156F145002601EB452D18E2801B8A4A5C5250021A4A71A61A004C52629DD690D0223346294D250048B4F069829C2801E280314829C280169452538500000A5C5252D030C52D20A5A004A434E3484500274A4341A4A003A5146681400530F5A7D34D003690D29E94D340094869690F4A0434F4A6E69C4E2A33220382EA0FA134013AD3853053C500381A70A65385003A9C2983AD385002D148294D031452D3681D280169294525002521A292800A4A0D3493400FCF14D26A22E6A269185005834C7758D4B3B0551D493802B9D9F56BBFEDA16A1C2C41B1803AF151594D25C69B7F1CCED20527058E4D006DCBAAD9C488DE6EE576D80AF233F5AA3FDB8D25EC968908475042B31CE48E9C57370B16D2AE14F446565F634B7933ADEDB4E0E24645627DE8037E1BF96EB4D13B362485FF7AA38C8EFFA573B796ED15DCA8BCA86C83ED5A560C5753BC847DC75C91535AB936E9900E323247A1C5007FFD9

Comment: The image data type can still store any kind of binary data (might not be an image at all, png, jpeg, OLE image object, etc), and any solution will depend on what kind of data is stored, so we can't answer this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display image from sql server in ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295044/how-to-display-image-from-sql-server-in-ms-access)

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I didn't clarify. It is storing jpg's